# How I can draw this Cartesian frame using latex?

Tags: diagrams, draw

[image: I want to draw this frame using Latex]

How can I draw it using latex? Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Among others, you can do that with  `pstricks` – more specifically the `pst-3dplot` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an orthographic projection. The standard tools nowadays are `asymptote`, `tikz-3dplot` and the `perspective` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,semithick,line cap=round,
    3d view={110}{15},%<- install 3d view and set view angles
    declare function={Mx=4;My=3;Mz=4;}%<- define the components of M
    ]
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) ;
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) ;
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) ;
 \draw[red,->] (0,0,0) -- (Mx,My,Mz)coordinate(M) node[pos=1.1]{$M$};
 \draw[green!70!black,->] (0,0,0) -- (Mx,My,0)coordinate(M') node[pos=1.2]{$M'$};
 \draw[dashed] (Mx,0,0) node[above left,red]{$x$} -- (Mx,My,0)
  -- (0,My,0) node[above,red]{$y$}
  (M') -- (M) -- (0,0,Mz) node[left,red]{$z$};
 \draw[->,cyan] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above left] {$\vec i$}; 
 \draw[->,cyan] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$\vec j$}; 
 \draw[->,cyan] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left] {$\vec k$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]